# how to implement bootstrap when printing <div> Containing another hidden <div> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

like i mention in the title i have a problem when i want to print a div> Containing another hidden div with javaScript the bootstrap styling gone

before pushing the print botton
[image]

after pushing the print botton
[image: after print order]

```js
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
            function myPrint() {
                var myPrintContent = document.getElementById('table');
                var myPrintWindow = window.open('','','');
                myPrintWindow.document.write(myPrintContent.innerHTML);
                myPrintWindow.document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display='block';
                myPrintWindow.document.close();
                myPrintWindow.focus();
                myPrintWindow.print();
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

```html
<div id=table>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <div style="display: none;" id="hidden_div">
                            <h1>hi</h1>
                </div>
                        <thead class="table-primary">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nom Article</th>
                                <th scope="col">CIN du responsable</th>
                                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Quantite</th>
                                <th class="text-center" scope="col" colspan="2" width="1%">Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="table-light">
                    <?php while($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse3)){
                        $donnees1=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select NOM_ARTICLE from article where ID_ARTICLE = $donnees[1]"));
                        $login_cin=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select CIN from utilisateurs where ID_LOGIN = $donnees[2]"));
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><?php echo $donnees[0];?></th>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees1[0]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $login_cin[0]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees[3]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees[4]; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="effectue_achat.php?id=<?php echo $donnees[0];?>"><img src="res\images\edit-icon.svg" height="30x" title="modifier"></a></td>
                                <td><a onclick="supprimer(<?php echo $donnees[0]; ?>)" href="#"><img src="res\images\delete-icon.svg" height="30x" title="supprimer"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                    }?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></div>
```

Comment: First, there are only a few valid elements that can be the child of a `table`, and `div` is not one of them. Then, what you're doing is essentially opening a completely **empty** new window and just writing the table into that window. Isn't it quite obvious that there will not be any styling since that window only contains HTML?

Comment: Have you tried a stylesheet specifically for print? ex - `@media print { ....`

Comment: @ChanMT because i have a form element and i dont want it to be printed.do i need to remove the div child ?

Comment: @BenRondeau no i use javascript

Comment: display: table-row is how you get a Bootstrap table row to be styled when you make it appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move the `hidden_div` out from the `table`.

```
<div id="table">
    <div style="display: none;" id="hidden_div">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead class="table-primary">
         ......
```

You can at least write the correct markup into the window you're opening, then provide the link to your CSS file (note that you'll need to put in the full URL):

```
<script>
    function myPrint() {
        var myPrintContent = document.getElementById('table');
        var myPrintWindow = window.open('','','');
        myPrintWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
        myPrintWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/your/bootstrap/css/path/your-bootstrap-theme.css">');
        myPrintWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        myPrintWindow.document.write(myPrintContent.innerHTML);
        myPrintWindow.document.write('</body></html>');            
        myPrintWindow.document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = 'block';
        myPrintWindow.document.close();
        myPrintWindow.focus();
        myPrintWindow.print();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Admittedly this is not the best way to print a webpage. As mentioned by @BenRondeau using `@media print` (learn more about media query [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)) to define a style specifically for printing is the appropriate method. Your current method might work, yes, but learn to do things the right way is always more beneficial in the long run.

Comment: yes thats work but like u see i use @media print in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap data tables, you need to use table-row instead of 'block'

This has been an issue I have experienced in the past, and that fixed it.

```
myPrintWindow.document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display='table-row';
```